# Is it possible to create a window in Java without the use of JFrame or anything similar?

Tags: java, window

I've used Java to develop applications for awhile, and always did something like this to make a window:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Yet how would I go about creating a window without using the JFrame or the Frame class? What actually goes on when I do this, and is it possible to do it in Java without this or would I need to use a lower level language like C++ or Assembly?

Comment: Ho ho, sorry to answer your question with a question, but why _wouldn't_ you want to use Swing?  Especially since you've used Java to develop applications for a while?

Comment: Joe it's not a matter of not wanting to use swing-- I want to see how it works at a lower level.

Comment: You will need to use JNI/JNA, this will allow you to create a window to your needs. The problem after that would then actually been able to attach anything to it.  Swing components share a common native peer (or window) and are built up via a internal native structure to support it. So, yes, while possible, the end functionality is very limiting...

Comment: Be warned, Java developers are *very* adamant about the use of Swing. Be ready to sustain a *lot* of flaming.

Comment: consider SWT https://www.eclipse.org/swt/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on the `JFrame` hierarchy.

You can create window in java using `JFrame` or its super class `JWindow`. You can also use `java.awt.Frame` and its super class `Window`. In all these cases you can create window (from OS perspective).

Comment: Yes, I did. This is the way I understood it. In the end of the day `Window` using `WindowPeer` calls native API, so if OP wants to know how does it work he can examine the source code of mentioned classes.

Comment: I wanted to do this without using anything that was pre-programmed for the specific purpose of creating a window.

Comment: I do not understand the term "without pre-programming". When you are writing code you are always using some kind of 3rd party. Even when you are programming in kernel mode. You obviously can use JNI/JNA to call native API, but why do you need java at all in this case?

Comment: I meant without using things that were made for the specific purpose of only creating a window. Read my full comment.